# Why does wget output to stderr rather than stdout?

Tags: linux, stdout, wget, stderr

After 30mins of futile attempt to capture the output of `wget`, I figured out that the program writes to `stderr` rather than the `stdout`. Searching in web and stack-overflow reveals this to be a well-known fact.

Any idea why is this so?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's well known, because it's in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Logging-and-Input-File-Options.html).

Reporting messages on `stderr` is common, because messages are separated from regular output on `stdout`. This is useful when you combine several tools with a pipe. In this case it would be bad, when regular output and diagnostic messages were mixed up.

Comment: I found the corresponding man page part while searching for output to a file !!

Comment: can we avoid this somehow?

Comment: You may redirect stderr to stdout `2>&1` or to some file `2>/tmp/err.out` or discard it `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/818255/1741542 for lots of answers about redirection.

Comment: I find this annoying, and a bad design decision. Download progress and other normal status messages are not error messages and shouldn't be output to stderr.