# Running wget using subprocess module, the normal output (channel 1) is redirecting to the error channel (channel 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, wget

```
def wget_url(url):     
   try:
        wget = subprocess.Popen(["wget "+url],shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
        return wget
   except:
        print("HTTP error")

a=wget_url(url)
a.stdout.readlines() #return an empty string.
a.stderr.readlines() #return the normal output that would be displayed in terminal
```

is this normal? Why stdout returns nothing?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Python problem but a feature of `wget`:

```
 wget url >  stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

Here `stdout.txt` is empty and `stdout.txt 2>` has the screen output with `200 OK`etc. This is a [well known fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066518/why-does-wget-output-to-stderr-rather-than-stdout).
Diagnostic messages could interfere with piping and therefore are better routed to stderr.